# Magento2 - Disabled modules causing errors in cron schedule

Tags: magento2, magento-cron

I have disabled the modules for all the `forced` third party modules - `temando`, `yotpo` etc.

But they still get added to the `cron` schedules and cause errors - even though the administration no longer shows the cron block

How is it possible that a disabled module still has code executed and how can I stop this?

The crontab.xml of at least some disabled modules are being added to the schedule even though the modules are disabled.

Is there a way to override a module that has defined a crontab.xml so that cron entries are removed, without removing files that are part of the M2 distribution?I know I can override the schedule, which would already be better, but is there a way to disable/remove?

UPDATE: would creating a separate cron group that generates schedules "almost never" work? is changing what cron group a crontab entry belongs to something I could override in a custom module?

Comment: Did you checked in crontab -e? Is there any other cron is available related to 3rd party modules?

Comment: That maybe already in queue, so now you have to manually delete them from table cron_schedule

Comment: I cleared cron_schedule and they reappear - both crons from modules not disabled but not used (eg amazon payments) but also from modules I disabled (eg new relic reporting) - clearly the config cron files are being read even for disabled modules

Comment: it's madness, newrelic even has a config option with cron disabled by default, so why are the entries popping up. Disabled option in a disabled module... will delete that crontab.xml file

Comment: obviously, deleting the file fixed it